# Change background image by pressing a menu item in android

Tags: android

Im creating simple notepad app in android,in options menu i have the "change background" as a menu item,when user clicks it,i just want to change the background image only [for example,i want to change my background image from efil tower to tajmahal],i have 10 images in drawable..how to change it randomly when everytime user clicks the "change background" option.Thank you.

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: Provide the code or approach you tried so far?

Comment: i post my codes in pastebin.com my activity [link](http://pastebin.com/Skq5PCaN) and my layout [link](http://pastebin.com/pa9KhYms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.eifel,R.drawable.tajmahal};
LinearLayout backLayout;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   backLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mybackgroundlayout);
}

private void changeBackground(){
 backLayout.setBackgroundResource(images[randInt(0,images.length-1)]);
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
 Random rand = new Random();
 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
 return randomNum;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.changebackground:
        changeBackground();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Errors are,Multiple markers at this line
 - images cannot be resolved or is not a field
 - randInt cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error on token ",", . expected
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
 - The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Drawable)

Comment: when i tried this code 'backLayout.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(images[randInt[0,images[].length]]));' ..it shows red underline in brackets

Comment: i have edited the answer.. you just need to add a missing ")" brace.try the changed answer

Comment: ok,now error is gone but i cant able to add return true; after the break statement.

Comment: edited again..try it..Are you new to android and Java ?

Comment: if you know java you must know how switch statement works.anyways i have edited the code..try it out

Comment: yes, u r ryt john,i know how switch statement works..but u dont understand my problem i think..it shows error in changebackground method and switch statement randomly,now it shows error in backlayout.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(images[randInt(0,images.length)])); i can understand logic @john

Comment: now app force closes john,can u see my activity code i posted..then u can understand my problem.when i click "change background" in menu item,my activity force closes

Comment: can you post the logcat output ? of the crash

Comment: can u understand it john,it is so long i cant able to understand whn i pasted in notepad...log cat crash [link](http://pastebin.com/tP1J9LYQ)

Comment: its an array out of bound exception ...i have edited the answer ..try it..added -1 in changebackground..

Comment: john,it didnt work,can u tell how to change it through styles.xml..coz i tried more methods by java code,again and again it fails..i think it can be done by xml

Comment: whats is the issue with this code.. is your background not changing  or is there any crash ?

Comment: And more over styles are used to change the theme of whole application and colors

Comment: Background not changing john

Comment: I have only two activities...i want to change the background image randomly in my second activity @john